# Efficient way to join elements under a conditional

Tags: list-manipulation

I am solving a certain challenge given by my friend.

I want to print the first day of the year if it is not a leap year, while I want both first and second days if it is a leap year.

I want to know if there is an efficient way to rewrite this piece of code:

```
If[Mod[year,4]==0,DayName/@{{year,1,1},{year,1,2}},{DayName[{year,1,1}]}]
```

Comment: As an aside: leap years are not years which are multiples of 4, the definition is slightly more complex

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is an alternate solution not using `If`:

```
Table[ DayName[ {year, 1, x} ], {x, 1 + Boole[ LeapYearQ[{year} ]]} ]
```

Answer (score 2):

`LeapYearQ` should be more reliable, in particular since special rules apply if the year is divisible by 100 or 400.

```
f = year \[Function] If[
   LeapYearQ[{year, 1, 1}],
   DayName /@ {{year, 1, 1}, {year, 1, 2}},
   {DayName[{year, 1, 1}]}
   ]
```

Comment: Thanks for that tip. But is there still a better way to write the rest of the code? I mean specifically for DayName part.

Comment: Hm. What does "better" mean? Are you concerned about efficiency? Why? How many years do you want to test this way?

Comment: I'm concerned about efficiency since it's a challenge. Nothing much.